how to block http://tplinkwifi.net/ url
let's say we are on windows 7, and we want to block a specific URL from getting resolved. one would assume to throw it into HOSTS file and job is done, but for some reason this does not work, so the question is how can we block it for good, as router keeps redirecting to it.
it is extremely annoying because that site does not work! here is what's happening:

router sits on 192.168.1.1
entering http://192.168.1.1/ into URL bar and pressing enter
the http://192.168.1.1/ is immediately redirected to http://tplinkwifi.net/
on http://tplinkwifi.net/ there is nothing to be done, so next we can do 2 things:

enter again http://192.168.1.1/ into URL bar and press enter

or on http://tplinkwifi.net/ click the link http://192.168.1.1/




the http://192.168.1.1/ loads and router can be finally managed
after 10-15 minutes of inactivity, http://192.168.1.1/ gets again auto-redirected to http://tplinkwifi.net/ and the loop repeats!!

HOSTS file failed attempts:
0.0.0.0 tplinkwifi.net
0.0.0.0 www.tplinkwifi.net
0.0.0.0 http://tplinkwifi.net
192.168.1.1 tplinkwifi.net
192.168.1.1 www.tplinkwifi.net
192.168.1.1 http://tplinkwifi.net


Which model is the router? Try to open the IP address of the router in incognito tab of the browser [link).

@harrymc I shall test this, thx. it's AXE75, RE200 and C6

Note that the hosts file should have only one line : 192.168.1.1  tplinkwifi.net.

@harrymc having only one line in HOSTS does not help. in incognito tab it looks like it does not get redirected but half of the time I'm getting error saying "unsupported browser" but with few refreshes it gets supported again

After the refreshes does the redirection loop start again?

@harrymc in incognito mode no. but in regular tab it still loops. not sure how those routers can ignore HOSTS file, but they do so somehow. I read some stuff on reddit somewhere that they track clicks with this redirect loop (no idea if thats true, even if, I dont care, it is just very annoying to access my routers as they keep redirecting to pointless unsecured sites)

I have found posts where the incognito mode trick was the only one that truly worked. Shall I put up an answer?

@harrymc no offense, but I would prefer an answer that would stay on track with question and deal with HOSTS file to somehow resolve the proper blocking capabilities. indeed I did not know about incognito workaround but if rly needed I am able to solve this with some 3rd-party redirect chrome extension, but still hoping for some HOSTS miracle

(No offense taken.) The hosts file might actually be working, and the redirection happens afterward. You may trace what's happening by using a tool such as Fiddler or Wireshark.

I had a thought : The main difference between incognito and normal modes are that the extensions are disabled. Try to disable your extensions and see if normal mode then works, to see if this is caused by an extension.

@harrymc tried that already. even tried with different browsers (opera, chrome, maxthon, brave, ...) fresh installs - its same on all of them.

I think the conclusion is then that the router itself is doing it. Nobody ever managed to explain why it works in incognito mode, not even Support.

Lets recap:
You have a windows 7 workstation
It is connected to a tplink router on the 192.168.1.0 network
If in a browser, on that workstation, you go to https://192.168.1.1 it redirects you to tplinkwifi.net, which is suboptimal behavior.
Attempting to fix this redirect in the workstations host file does not solve the issue.
Well, there is good news and bad news.
The bad news is you are trying to solve a known issue.  The TP link device has a reverse proxy built into it that is not configurable to consumers that forces a redirect to tplinkwifi.net if you try to access the device by IP address. 'Clear your browser cache' is a boilerplate copout.
The good news is you are on the right path to a workaround.   A true solution will only come from TPLink fixing a 2+ year old known issue.
Options to move forward:

access your router in incognito mode
this will work way more often than you think.

hosts file entry
you only need to make 1 entry: the router ip and the domain
edit the file as an administrator
192.168.1.1 tplinkwifi.net


leave out all the http and www entries, just use that one.
restarting your browser will not pick up these entries.
reboot, or run ipconfig /flushdns

browser user scripts

find a browser user script add-on, and plug this in and next time it happens it should scoot you back to where you wanted to go.
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Go back from tplinkwifi.net
// @namespace   /
// @match       http://tplinkwifi.net/
// @version     1.0
// @author      -
// @description Go back from tplinkwifi.net
// ==/UserScript==

window.history.go(-1);


spam tplink with your hatred, get them to stop doing this asshattery.

go outside, never compute again (not recommended)



overall, I am not satisfied with this answer, but bounty points would be wasted, if not awarded, so enjoy. 1. is nice workaround but unpractical. I access my routers 5-6x a day. 2. does not work even after flush. I have 1K entries and every of them works but not 192.168.1.1 tplinkwifi.net 3. could work (not tested) but I just dont wanna go that route. 4. already did and still doing it but no one cares. everyone acts like its a cool feature not a bug. at this point I just gave up and offered all tplink products for sale. its a stupid lying  brand!
